# pip - Requirement already satisfied?

Tags: virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper

pip recognize global installed packages..?!  :-(

I've used virtualenvwrapper preactivate hook to clean PYTHONPATH,

```
export PYTHONPATH=""
```

then echo $PYTHONPATH returns empty string, but this didn't help.

What's wrong?

```
bentzy@lama:~$ mkvirtualenv test
New python executable in test/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/bentzy/.virtualenvs/test/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/bentzy/.virtualenvs/test/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/bentzy/.virtualenvs/test/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/bentzy/.virtualenvs/test/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/bentzy/.virtualenvs/test/bin/get_env_details
(test)bentzy@lama:~$ which pip
/home/bentzy/.virtualenvs/test/bin/pip
(test)bentzy@lama:~$ sudo pip install simplejson
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplejson in /usr/lib    /python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
(test)bentzy@lama:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH

(test)bentzy@lama:~$ pip --version
pip 1.2.1 from /home/bentzy/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

Comment: I haven't used virtualenvwrapper, but with virtualenv I use the  --no-site-packages option.  Can mkvirtualenv pass this option?

Comment: Yes - but tis is not the issue. As of virtualenv 1.7, the --no-site-packages has become the default and is deprecated. Im using 1.8.2.
Anyway - I've also tried that and still didn't work as expected...

Comment: Try printing `sys.path` and see what's there.

Comment: What does `pip freeze` say?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are using `sudo` to install simplejson, but if you use `sudo` your `$PATH` may be changed, and that seems to be the problem.

Just use `pip install simplejson` (no `sudo` included) and it is probably going to work.

Use `sudo` only when you want to affect your whole system.

Comment: Also the ``--user`` option may make sense, which will install it in your ``~/.local/lib/...`` directory. This does not require r00t privileges.

Answer (score 12):

Already satisfied means that you already install "it".

try: 
**pip uninstall simplejson**

and then:
**pip install simplejson**