# Python packages not installing in virtualenv using pip

Tags: python, twisted, virtualenv, pip

**I'm having trouble installing twisted**

```
pip --version
```

> pip 1.1 from
>   /home/chris/GL/GLBackend/glenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg
>   (python 2.7)

**Create a virtual environment**

```
chris@chris-mint ~/GL/GLBackend $ sudo virtualenv -p python2.7 glenv
```

> Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7 New python
>   executable in glenv/bin/python2.7 Also creating executable in
>   glenv/bin/python Installing
>   distribute.............................................................................................................................................................................................done.
>   Installing pip...............done.

**Just in case, I'll enable all permissions**

```
chris@chris-mint ~/GL/GLBackend $ sudo chmod -R 777 glenv

chris@chris-mint ~/GL/GLBackend $ source glenv/bin/activate


(glenv)chris@chris-mint ~/GL/GLBackend $ pip freeze
```

> argparse==1.2.1 distribute==0.6.24 wsgiref==0.1.2

**twisted is not listed here as installed**

```
(glenv)chris@chris-mint ~/GL/GLBackend $ sudo pip install twisted
```

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twisted in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages Requirement already satisfied
>   (use --upgrade to upgrade): zope.interface>=3.6.0 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from twisted) Requirement
>   already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from
>   zope.interface>=3.6.0->twisted) Cleaning up... (glenv)chris@chris-mint
>   ~/GL/GLBackend $ pip uninstall twisted Cannot uninstall requirement
>   twisted, not installed Storing complete log in
>   /home/chris/.pip/pip.log

**But when I install it it says that its already installed.
Force the install:**

```
sudo pip install -I twisted
```

> Downloading/unpacking twisted Downloading Twisted-12.3.0.tar.bz2
>   (2.6Mb): 2.6Mb downloaded Running setup.py egg_info for package
>   twisted
>        . . .
>
> Successfully installed twisted zope.interface distribute Cleaning
>   up...

**And yet it still isn't installed**

```
(glenv)chris@chris-mint ~/GL/GLBackend $ pip freeze
```

> argparse==1.2.1 distribute==0.6.24 wsgiref==0.1.2

**When I try running Python scripts which use twisted, I get an error saying that twisted is not installed. That is:

> ImportError: No module named twisted.python**

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` with `pip install` under `virtualenv`? I don't know for sure that `pip` tries to install to the system (that is, to put still in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7`, as you're seeing, instead of `~/glenv`, as you want) when you use `sudo`, but it's at least plausible. (You also shouldn't use `sudo` to create your venv in the first place.)

Comment: @abarnert already answered you, and you seem to be experiencing the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/q/14665330/565999

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using `sudo` when you shouldn't be. And that's causing `pip` to try to install into `/usr/local/lib` instead of `~/glenv/lib`. (And, because you used `sudo`, it's successfully doing so, but that doesn't help you, because you're not allowing system site-packages in your venv.)

There are multiple reasons `sudo pip` could lead to this behavior, but the most likely is this: On most systems (including the various Mac and RHEL/CentOS boxes I have immediate access to), the `sudoers` file will reset your environment, then add back in a handful of whitelisted environment variables. This means that when you `sudo pip`, it will not see the environment variables that `virtualenv` sets up, so it will fall back to doing the default thing and install into your system Python, instead of your venv.

But really, it doesn't matter *why* this is happening. The answer is the same: just do `pip install` instead of `sudo pip install`.

Note that you *also* want to remove the `sudo` on the `virtualenv` call, as this will probably cause the venv to be set up incorrectly (which is why you need the `sudo chmod`, which wouldn't be necessary otherwise). The whole point of installing things under your user home directory is that you can do it with your normal user permissions.

As a side note, you also may want to upgrade to a newer `virtualenv`/`pip`, as 1.8 and 1.2 have some bug fixes and improvements. But I verified that I get exactly the same problem as you even with the latest (1.8.4 and 1.2.1) versions, so I don't think that's relevant here.

Comment: What about if I want to install my `virtualenv` in the `/opt` folder? I am receiving a `Permission Denied` error.

Comment: @Giri: you can make a subdirectory using sudo, give your user or group permission, and then do all the virtualenv stuff there without sudo. If it's for a normal user you might prefer to use their homedir though.

Answer (score 0):

The `sudo pip` is causing the problem here. It will install the package in your system instead of the virtual environment you created. So when it says the requirement is already satisfied. Try to look add the directory it is pointing to. Which is in your case, while you were trying to install, was `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

If it's inside something like `/usr/local/lib/...`, which does not points to your virtualenv folder then it is installed in your system. Otherwise, in correct scenario it will look something like this `/usr/local/lib/..../<name of your virtualenv>/lib`.

You can always use commands like `which python` & `which pip` to see if they both are using the placeholder of our virtual environment.