# "Error: No module named haystack" after installing django haystack inside virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, django-haystack, virtualenvwrapper

I am having trouble getting django-haystack installed on my production server.

I get the error `No module named haystack` when I run any of the following commands:
`python manage.py syncdb`
`python manage.py runserver`
`python manage.py shell`

This is a clone of an existing project running on a development server, so I believe my settings.py is configured correctly.

I am working inside a virtualenv. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling django-haystack several times using pip.

What could be causing this error?

UPDATE:

Got some more data from following these steps:

Inside virtualenv: `pip freeze` - django-haystack is not listed.
Outside virtualenv: `pip freeze` - django-haystack is listed.
Outside virtualenv: `sudo pip uninstall django-haystack`
Outside virtualenv: `pip freeze` - django-haystack is not listed.
Inside virtualenv: `which pip` - /home/{user}/.virtualenvs/{virtualenv}/bin/pip
Inside virtualenv: `sudo pip install django-haystack` 
Inside virtualenv: `pip freeze` - django-haystack is still not listed. 
Outside virtualenv: `pip freeze` - django-haystack is listed.

Curious isn't it?
I am using virtualenvwrapper (if you couldn't tell from the pip path)

Why is pip installing it (and some other packages I noticed) outside my virtualenv?

Comment: did you include django-haystack in Installed Apps in settings.py?

Comment: Are you sure you've install haystack into the virtualenv? Check `which pip` before installing.

Comment: Yes and yes. I have haystack listed in installed_apps and django-haystack is being installed into the virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks. Could you show your settings?

Comment: Settings.py pasted here: http://pastebin.com/e6yj6z3V. Another thing to note is that haystack is included in installed_apps via django-oscar with the get_core_apps method. I have also tried adding haystack explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer here: [Python packages not installing in virtualenv using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695278/python-packages-not-installing-in-virtualenv-using-pip)

The problem was that I was using sudo with pip in my virtualenv. As a result, pip was installing outside of my virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip uninstall haystack

pip install django-haystack
```