# Python can't see modules installed with pip

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I'm working in a brand new Python virtualenv. I've just installed `httplib2` using pip, but Python cannot see it.

```
(venv)$ sudo pip install httplib2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2 in     
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
(venv)$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httplib2
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named httplib2
```

From my reading, it sounds like this is probably a path problem, but I don't know why it is happening, or how to fix it :(

This is the content of `sys.path`:

```
>>> pprint(sys.path)
['',
 '/var/apps/ttex/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/var/apps/ttex/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/var/apps/ttex/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/var/apps/ttex/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/var/apps/ttex/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/var/apps/ttex/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/var/apps/ttex/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/var/apps/ttex/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/var/apps/ttex/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/var/apps/ttex/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/var/apps/ttex/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Oddly though, if I run Python 2.7, I can see the package:

```
(venv)$ python2.7
>>> import httplib2
>>>
```

Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, there are lots of questions around this topic, but none seem to give a simple definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it without the sudo in a fresh virtualenv. Pip thinks that you want to install it in global scope, so to /usr, not in your sandbox.

[Python packages not installing in virtualenv using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695278/python-packages-not-installing-in-virtualenv-using-pip)