# Flask can't see modules installed by pip

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I installed Flask on Python 2.7.12/Apache 2.4/Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.  I've been using [these](http://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2015/02/24/running-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2/) [two](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/) tutorials to get set up.  I'm not running `venv` or any other virtual environment (unlike [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656118/python-cant-see-modules-installed-with-pip)).  Running a simple Flask app works fine (a la "hello world").  I have a **flaskapp.wsgi** and a **flaskapp.py** in the same directory (/var/www/html).

**flaskapp.wsgi**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/html/flaskapp")
from flaskapp import app as application
```

**flaskapp.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return "hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

But when I try to import a module outside of the basic set of Flask modules, eg. `httplib2` (which I installed via `pip`), I get a 500 HTTP error.  Simply adding `import httplib2` to **flaskapp.py** throws this error.

Looking at the Apache error logs I see the following:

```
[wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=22739): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=22739): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi'.
[wsgi:error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error] File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[wsgi:error] from flaskapp import app as application
[wsgi:error] File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.py", line 7, in <module>
[wsgi:error] import httplib2
[wsgi:error] ImportError: No module named httplib2
```

When I run `python` (not using Flask), I can import `httplib2` without trouble. So it seems for some reason my Flask app can't access pip's imports.

Here's what I've done to troubleshoot so far:

I checked to see where `httplib2` lives, using `__file__`:

```
>>> import httplib2
>>> httplib2.__file__
'/home/andrew/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.pyc'
```

Then I checked both `sys.path` and `pip.get_installed_distributions()` from within the Flask app:

**flaskapp.py** (revised)

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import pip, sys

modules = ""
for i in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    modules = modules + " " + str(i)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return jsonify({ "modules":modules, "sys.path":sys.path })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

output:

```
{
  "available_modules": " Flask 0.12 Jinja2 2.9.5 itsdangerous 0.24 Werkzeug 0.11.15 MarkupSafe 0.23 click 6.7", 
  "sys.path": [
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/lockfile-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/retrying-1.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/ipaddress-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/colorama-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/distlib-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/pyparsing-2.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/packaging-16.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/html5lib-0.999-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/chardet-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/progress-1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-20.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl", 
    "/var/www/html/flaskapp", 
    "/usr/lib/python2.7", 
    "/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu", 
    "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk", 
    "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old", 
    "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload", 
    "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages", 
    "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"
  ]
}
```

So it can see the path where `httplib2` lives, as well as the path to `flask`, but the available modules are only the Flask modules.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my Apache configuration - I've consulted a number of how-tos and documentation, and this is the setup I've been using:

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5 python-path=/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory  /var/www/html/flaskapp>
       WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
       WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
       Require all granted
       WSGIScriptReloading On
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I've looked through a number of SO posts, but most seem concerned with `app` not being visible to WSGI.  [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418012/my-apache-wsgi-flask-web-app-cannot-import-its-internal-python-module) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070658/apache-wsgi-to-run-flask-get-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-or?noredirect=1&lq=1) seem close, but haven't solved my problem. I'd really appreciate any advice!

Note: I'm pretty comfortable with Python, familiar-ish with Flask, but pretty novice with Apache and WSGI.  Detailed explanations/links for answers concerning the latter two topics (if appropriate) would really help.

Comment: That is a really cool piece of code you have there the flask app which tells you the installed packages and their paths, very helpful to diagnose if it's working and it renders nicely in the browser too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `~/.local/` to python-path on your Apache configuration.

`WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5 python-path=/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp:/home/andrew/.local`

You should also try to use virtual environments, and set python-home on WSGIDaemonProcess as the environment root.

Source: http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html

#### EDIT

You can also install `httplib2` with `sudo` just like you installed the `flask` packages (as seen in [one of your links](http://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2015/02/24/running-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2/))

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  Adding `/home/andrew/.local/` as instructed didn't solve the problem.  I understand virtual environments are a good idea, but shouldn't this be possible to do without using them?

Comment: You could try to install httplib2 with `sudo` just like you installed the flask package. I'm sorry if I misread your question, did not see that you are not using `venv`

Comment: It is recommended that you do not use per user packages directory with mod_wsgi. They are bad for various reasons. Use a proper Python virtual enviormnent. If you you still want to use per user ``site-packages``, the path should have been ``/home/andrew/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`` and not ``/home/andrew/.local`` that you used with ``python-path`` option.

Comment: (I'm assuming the `sudo` from the links on your question)

Comment: @RicardoBusquet uninstalling `httplib2` and reinstalling with `sudo` solved the problem.  Would you mind updating the main answer?  Thank you!!

Comment: Just went and tested with my original `python-path`, and it works.  So the `~/.local/` addition wasn't necessary in my case.