# pip install -r requirement.txt on virtualenv doesn't install locally but globally, even after activation

Tags: pip, installation, virtualenv, requirements.txt

I tried to install all dependencies in my `requirements.txt` (a bunch of packages list).
What I did:

- created virtual env `virtualenv my_env`
- activated the new virtual env, I'm able to see my virtual env before the prompt `(my_env) $`
- ran `pip install -r requirements.txt`

All packages got installed, but when checking with `pip freeze` I have nothing. Tried to deactivate the virtual env, and made `pip freeze` again, here I have all installed.

I'm a bit confused because, I'm very sure my virtual env was activated, and I have the right pip path when doing `which pip` inside it (`/home/virtual_env/my_env/bin/pip`). Plus, I tried to install one by one the dependency, and they got installed right inside the virtual env & displayable with `pip freeze`

I cannot do all of them one by one, and I need to reproduce the installation somewhere. Could someone helps on this?

Comment: Sometimes using `python -m pip command ...` instead of `pip command ...` helps. Make sure the `python` binary is also the right one with `which python`.

Comment: Did you use `sudo`?

Comment: No I didn't use sudo.

Comment: found another related tickets but none of provided solution worked :( : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942982/virtualenv-pip-trying-to-install-packages-globally

Comment: Anything helpful in the verbose, or debug output?

Comment: Anything helpful in the verbose

Answer (score 0):

Still no clean solution for this so far, but what would work is to copy-edit (search & replace the `return` character in the `requirements.pip` to `&& pip install`. Meaning, edit it from this format

```
package1==vX.Y
package2==vU.V
...
```

into this

```
package1==vX.Y && pip install package2==vU.V ...
```

Add pip install at the beginning then make a copy to all for install command like

```
pip install package1==vX.Y && pip install package2==vU.V ...
```