# Can't install library into virtual environment

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, django-haystack

I created virtual environment for Django procject using Pycharm and Anaconda. The problem is that I can not install django-haystack library into virtual environment. 
I tried installing it with anaconda, pycharm itself and tried using `pip install django-haystack`. Using pip install I can see that library is installed.

```
Installing collected packages: django-haystack
Successfully installed django-haystack-2.8.1
```

I saw post earlier which had similar problem where libraries were installed in python  "[[Python packages not installing in virtualenv using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695278/python-packages-not-installing-in-virtualenv-using-pip[1]) " but here the solution was not to use `sudo` installing library, but I am not using it.

Does anybody know how can I install this library into virtual environment ? I run everything on windows

**Update on the issue**

using pip freeze output I can see that django-haystack is installed:

```
Django==2.1
django-haystack==2.8.1
elasticsearch==6.3.0
```

But still then I run `py -3 manage.py startapp search` I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'haystack'
```

This is how my settings.py file looks :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'haystack'
]

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'localhost:9200',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

`py -3 -m site` output:

```
sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\Joha\\PycharmProjects\\untitled1',
    'C:\\Python\\python36.zip',
    'C:\\Python\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Python\\lib',
    'C:\\Python',
    'C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: 'C:\\Users\\Joha\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: 'C:\\Users\\Joha\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

where pip output:
`C:\Users\Joha\Anaconda3\envs\test_haystack\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Python\Scripts\pip.exe`

where py output:
`C:\Windows\py.exe`

Ok so the problem was that pip has two paths. How can I remove one of the paths, so it would use just virtenv but not global path ?

Comment: What do you mean by " Using pip install I can see that library is installed, but I can not find it in virtual environment directory."?

Comment: `pip freeze` and post output here

Comment: @itzMEonTV updated issue to answer your questions.

Comment: Can you post the output of `which py`, `which pip` and `py -3 -m site`?

Comment: `which py` and `which pip` does not work for me. I get 
`'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
`.
@NilsWerner added output of `py -3 -m site` in the questions

Comment: Replace `which` with `where` on Windows.