# pip freeze not showing packages

Tags: python, pip

For example if after installing Tornado with pip like this:

```
pip install tornado
Collecting tornado
...
Successfully installed backports-abc certifi singledispatch six tornado
```

`pip freeze` doesn't return tornado package in list, it just shows:

```
PyMySQL==0.7.2
```

also when I run `easy_install` it returns:

```
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /lib/python2.7/site-packages/

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

    ''
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using virtualenvwrapper or another virtual environment (which is probably not your case but is how I arrived at this question), you may have installed things using `sudo` which will install them for your entire system. ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665330/pip-requirement-already-satisfied))

Therefore, `pip freeze` actually is working, you just haven't actually installed anything with that pip.

Answer (score 1):

1. I suppose reinstalling pip may help you:

   ```
   pip install --upgrade pip
   ```
2. To fix easy_install problem add `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` to your PYTHONPATH:

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
   ```

**Good Luck !**

Answer (score 0):

upgrade `pip` and it will work. I had the exact same problem. In my case it wasn't "`sudo`" related, but upgrading pip via `pip install --upgrade pip` solved the issue.