# How do I import and use Pygal for Python 3.7.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, python-module, pygal

I've used `pip3 install pygal` to install Pygal. My terminal tells me:

> Requirement already satisfied: pygal in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
>   (2.4.0)

The pygal documentation page says pygal is only available for python 2.7 and 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 and pypy.

So! What is one to do if they're working with Python 3.7.4??

In case it matters, I'm working with a macOS 10.14.6

Comment: Despite what the sparsely updated documentation says, Pygal works in Python > 3.5. Based on your `pip3` output, it is installed in your 3.7 interpreter. I am unsure what your question actually is, though. Judging by the question title, you are looking for some sort of a Pygal tutorial. If that is the case, I'm afraid SO is the wrong place for that request. If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue is that when I Build on Sublime Text, I get the following message:

`ImportError: No module named pygal`

I assumed this was because the import/installation had not worked due to the python version. But perhaps there is something else afoot here?

Comment: Please verify that Sublime uses the same Python interpreter that you installed Pygal in. I am not too familiar with macOS; Sublime might use the system interpreter by default, or a system-wide side-packages folder, rather than a local one, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665330/pip-requirement-already-satisfied). Start an interactive session by calling `python3` in your console and try to import Pygal from there. If that works, your problem is likely related to Sublime using a different interpreter/env than what your installation was perfomed in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I ended up bypassing the problem by using Visual Studio Code. Thanks a bunch though!